# Georeferencer in graphical modeler QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, qgis-modeler

Is it possible to automate georeferencing in graphical modeler, I want to extract images from a site and georeference them with QGIS. Graphical modeler algorithms won't show Georeferencer.

Comment: How would be the workflow you want to automate? If i think about georeferencing, it needs a person to link the new ungeoref. input with correct coordinates. Or do you simply want to set a certain projection to a file?

Comment: Hi!, the workflow goes:
- Input image (downloaded from a website)
- Georeferencing the image (I have already a "points" file to georeference the image)
- The georeferenced image will be clipped (taking out the legend part of the original image)
-  I need to convert this clipped georeferenced image to vector (polygons)
- Resulting polygons will be clipped with a boundary layer to have statistics from grouping administrative boundaries.

Comment: ..but you need to georeference manually right? Or how would you like to do the georeferencing part? I think there is no algorithm to automate this because it needs a human being.

Comment: I would like to do the georeference part automated because I would use same points to georeference, an image is generated every ten days (so there are several images to compare to).